# Exact number of nested ranked data exact in SQL procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a procedure like this:

```
SELECT Name, Date, Par3, Date_rank
FROM
   (SELECT Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY Par3 ASC) 
   AS Date_rank
   FROM Table
   WHERE (..conditions..)) ranked
WHERE Par2_rank <= 3
ORDER BY Par2 ASC, Par3 ASC
```

The result gives me if number of rows is less or equal 3 is:

```
Name,    Date,     Par3,    Date_rank
AB   2010-01-01    1.5          1
CD   2010-02-16    0.9          1
EF   2010-02-16    1.1          2
GH   2010-02-16    1.7          3
```

But I need only results, where we have exact number of rows for date, equal 3.
So the result should be:

```
Name,    Date,     Par3,    Date_rank
CD   2010-02-16    0.9          1
EF   2010-02-16    1.1          2
GH   2010-02-16    1.7          3
```

I tried to put `WHERE Par2_rank = 3`.

Then I get only one row:

```
Name,    Date,     Par3,    Date_rank
GH   2010-02-16    1.7          3
```

Also I tried to use `HAVING COUNT`, but it gives me no rows.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
Thanks to all you guys for quick answers. COUNT (*) OVER PARTITION did the trick. It's so simple.. I hope, I will code better in SQL thanks to you in the future.

Comment: For first row there is date ` 2010-01-01` so what wrong in this?

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Zohar, thanks for a tip. Next time I will added. For this topci I got answers so quick, so I late with update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, try the following approach using `SUM()` with `OVER` clause, but without `ORDER BY`:

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table (
    Name varchar(2),
    [Date] date,
    Par3 numeric(5, 1)
)
INSERT INTO #Table
    (Name, [Date], Par3)
VALUES
    ('AB', '20100101', 1.5),
    ('AB', '20100101', 1.6),
    ('AB', '20100102', 1.5),
    ('AC', '20100102', 1.6),
    ('AD', '20100102', 1.7),
    ('AE', '20100102', 1.8),
    ('CD', '20100216', 0.9),
    ('EF', '20100216', 1.1),
    ('GH', '20100216', 1.7)
```

T-SQL:

```
SELECT Name, [Date], Par3, Rn
FROM (
    SELECT 
        Name, 
        [Date], 
        Par3, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Date] ORDER BY Par3 ASC) AS Rn,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [Date]) As Cnt
    FROM #Table
    ) ranked
WHERE Cnt = 3
```

Output:

```
------------------------------
Name    Date        Par3    Rn
------------------------------
CD      2010-02-16  0.9     1
EF      2010-02-16  1.1     2
GH      2010-02-16  1.7     3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH cte_ranked
AS
(
 SELECT Name, [Date], Par3
       ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [Date]) As DateCount
 FROM Table
 )

SELECT Name, [Date], Par3
FROM cte_ranked
WHERE DateCount = 3
ORDER BY [Date], Par3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using EXISTS:

```
WITH ranked AS
(
    SELECT Name, date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY Par3 ASC) 
       AS Date_rank
       FROM Table
       WHERE (..conditions..)
) 
SELECT 
    *
FROM ranked AS R
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM ranked
                    where r.Date = Date
                    and Date_rank = 3
                    and Date_rank <> 4
                  )
```